# javascript game: making player jump and landing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a javascript game, using canvas. I want to make a character(player) jump and land on the next coming log when the keyboard(37) is pressed. So, I tried to make an array containg y position of log when updated, and the player land on the y position of the log in the array in a regular sequence when the keyboard is pressed. [image]

However, it works weird. The player doesn't land on the planned y position of the log, and sometimes suddenly moves to other position while jumping, and the player goes to y position without jumping when pressing keyboard first time(second time and after, it jumps well). I really don't know the reason for several days...Is there something wrong in the below code? How can I solve the problem?

This is a github address that includes all the files related game.
https://github.com/psh5487/lionTravel.git

Among them, RS_PlayGame.js is directly related with the jumping and landing.

RS_PlayGame.js

```
function PlayGameState()
{
    //player
    this.sprPlayer = new SpriteAnimation(resourcePreLoader.GetImage("/.c9/img/game_player.png"), 125, 167, 4, 4);
    this.x = 150;
    this.y = 200;

    this.Invalid();

    this.isJumpingUp = false;
    this.jumpPower = 0;

    //log
    this.imgShortlog1 = resourcePreLoader.GetImage("/.c9/img/game_shortlog.png");
    this.imgShortlog2 = resourcePreLoader.GetImage("/.c9/img/game_shortlog.png");
    this.imgShortlog3 = resourcePreLoader.GetImage("/.c9/img/game_shortlog.png");

    //moving logs
    this.posShortlog1 = 0+200;
    this.speedShortlog1 = 7;

    this.posShortlog2 = 315+200;
    this.speedShortlog2 = 7;

    this.posShortlog3 = 625+200;
    this.speedShortlog3 = 7;

    //default y position of log
    this.y_log_position_Arr = new Array(3);
    this.y_log_position_Arr[0] = 350;
    this.y_log_position_Arr[1] = 300;
    this.y_log_position_Arr[2] = 350;

    //player position after jumping
    this.afterjump_Arr = new Array();
    this.afterjump_Arr[0] = 350;
    this.afterjump_Arr[1] = 300;
    this.afterjump_Arr[2] = 350;

    this.i = 0;
}

PlayGameState.prototype.Render = function()
{
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("GameCanvas");
    var Context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

    //drawing log
    Context.drawImage(this.imgShortlog1, this.posShortlog1, this.y_log_position_Arr[0], 170, 32);
    Context.drawImage(this.imgShortlog2, this.posShortlog2, this.y_log_position_Arr[1], 170, 32);
    Context.drawImage(this.imgShortlog3, this.posShortlog3, this.y_log_position_Arr[2], 170, 32);

    //drawing player
    this.sprPlayer.Render(Context);
};

PlayGameState.prototype.Update = function()
{ 
    this.sprPlayer.Update();

    //moving log
    this.posShortlog1 -= this.speedShortlog1;
    this.posShortlog2 -= this.speedShortlog2;
    this.posShortlog3 -= this.speedShortlog3;

    if(this.posShortlog1 < -170)
    {
        this.posShortlog1 = 800;

        var y_position_values_ud = [350, 300, 250];
        var position_index_ud = getRandomInt(3);
        var y_log_position_ud = y_position_values_ud[position_index_ud];

        this.y_log_position_Arr[0] = y_log_position_ud;

        this.afterjump_Arr.push(this.y_log_position_Arr[0]);
    }

    if(this.posShortlog2 < -170)
    {
        this.posShortlog2 = 800;

        var y_position_values_ud = [350, 300, 250];
        var position_index_ud = getRandomInt(3);
        var y_log_position_ud = y_position_values_ud[position_index_ud];

        this.y_log_position_Arr[1] = y_log_position_ud;

        this.afterjump_Arr.push(this.y_log_position_Arr[1]);
    }

    if(this.posShortlog3 < -170)
    {
        this.posShortlog3 = 800;

        var y_position_values_ud = [350, 300, 250];
        var position_index_ud = getRandomInt(3);
        var y_log_position_ud = y_position_values_ud[position_index_ud];

        this.y_log_position_Arr[2] = y_log_position_ud;

        this.afterjump_Arr.push(this.y_log_position_Arr[2]);
    }

    //keyboard control
    if(this.isJumpingUp == false)
    {
        if(inputSystem.isKeyDown(37))
        {
            this.isJumpingUp = true;
            this.jumpPower = -17;
            this.i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.y += this.jumpPower;
        this.jumpPower += 1;

        if(this.y >= this.afterjump_Arr[this.i]-150)
        {
            this.y = this.afterjump_Arr[this.i]-150;

            this.isJumpingUp = false;
        }
        this.Invalid();
    }
};

PlayGameState.prototype.Invalid = function()
{
    this.sprPlayer.SetPosition(this.x, this.y);
};

//getting random number
function getRandomInt(num)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
}
```

Comment: Can you share some details of how is the player supposed to behave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your game on GitHub and tried to understand what you are doing.

The code is not easy to follow, you have a mix of Object Oriented and Functional programming, I removed a few of the game elements and slowed down the game to shows some debug info on how the player jumps, so right now my fork is technically just an animation with the player jumping:
https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/lionTravel/master/index.html

The reason why the player doesn't land on the log is on this line of code:

```
    if(this.y >= this.afterjump_Arr[1]-150)
    {
        this.y = this.afterjump_Arr[1]-150;

        this.isJumpingUp = false;
    }
```

You are not comparing against the logs but a fixed variable, You could position the player to the right to give the illusion that it jumps on the right place, but you will not be able to move the player left or right with the keys, as soon as you let the player move horizontally this illusion show the real problem.

I recommend you to take some more courses on game development, that way you get a better understanding of collisions between game elements.

Comment: If you have time I recommend you to take this course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/interactive-python-1 ... it will give you a good base for building video games